# Invalid Partition table when trying to boot from USB on windows system

Tags: dual-boot, usb, kubuntu, windows-10, xps

So I've been trying to use a Kubuntu ISO on USB to boot and then create a new partition on my fully Windows 10 partitioned Dell XPS 13 for a full install. I have followed the recommended steps in terms of BIOS settings but whenever I select the USB as boot device on startup I run into 'Invalid partition table'. I haven't been able to find threads for this specific dual boot case so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you create the bootable USB?

Comment: @danzel I followed this guide
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Comment: which of the many alternatives on that site did you choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how you could have followed the guide you linked from a windows. that guide has you run ubuntu software from the ubuntu desktop.

let's just finish creating your USB with a correct guide, you still have the ISO right?

1. Download : [Rufus](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/releases/download/v3.5/rufus-3.5.exe)
2. Install it
3. run it
4. select your kubuntu ISO
5. set the partition type to GPT :

   [image: GPT partition type]
6. start

Comment: Rufus is actually mentioned on the site the OP linked to.

Comment: fair enough. do you think the OP saw it hidden down there, though?

Comment: Well, they said they followed _some_ guide, so I guess they actually used Rufus but didn't select GPT. Therefore, +1.

Comment: Checking the GPT selection seems to have fixed it, thanks!

Comment: no problem ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my Dell Latitude 5440. For me the issue was that the system was trying to Legacy boot, but it needed to boot via UEFI. The solution was this:

From the BIOS I went to "Other Options" -> "BIOS setup" -> "Advanced Boot Options" and unchecked "Enable Legacy Option ROMs", and the system booted just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18.04 here. In my case the issue was resolved once I switched to UEFI mode in my BIOS settings.

Press F2 to enter Boot settings.

Settings -> Boot Sequence -> Boot List Options -> check UEFI -> USB Drive